# Django ImportError No module named x.settings

Tags: python, django

I have the following structure:

```
mysite
  -> manage.py
  -> mysite (again)
        -> __init__.py
        -> wsgi.py
        -> settings.py
         etc
  -> myapp
        -> __init__.py            
        -> myscript.py
        -> models.py
        etc
```

When I run a script from myapp (that does myapp-related things, putting stuff in a the database for example) i need to do

```
import django
django.setup()
```

in order to be able to `from models import MyModel`. But if i do this in the myapp directory, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named mysite.settings
```

Which I kind of understand since it's further up the directory tree and not in the  same directory as e.g `manage.py` (the root I guess?). When I issue a python interpreter in mysite where `manage.py` is located, I dont get this error.

What should I do to be able to place my scripts in myapp and still be able to use `django.setup()` from that dir?

Comment: Do you try using '.' in front of the from `models import MyModel` the models should be `.models import MyModel`

Comment: If you're using Django and need to run some scripts within the context of your app you should use management commands: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the root of your project is in python path when you run the script. Something like this might help.

```
import os
import sys
projpath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(projpath, '..'))
```